# How do I change an ext4 hard drive back to Mac OS

Tags: uninstall, macosx

A friend recently gave me his old MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I really want to install Mac OS on it so I downloaded an installer and ran it on a USB. I got the installer up and running but it would not recognize the internal hard drive because it was formatted to ext4. How can I change the hard disk back to Mac OS Extended??

Comment: is there not a disk tool on the osx disk? Look in the menu for disks, it should be able to format it's own disk...

Comment: Close voters: formatting a hard disk from ubuntu is most certainly on-topic on a site about Ubuntu...!

Answer (score 2):

Head over to [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and download Ubuntu. Then follow [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to burn the downloaded ISO image to a flash drive. Once that's done reboot the computer and boot to the USB, clicking "try ubuntu" when the option presents itself.

You will need a few packages to add HFS support, so connect the machine to the network, then open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsutils hfsprogs
```

Once the installation process has finished, open gparted and find the ext4 partitions you want to reformat. Right click on them and select Format to -> hfs+.

[image]

Follow through on any prompts, and then let the program do its thing. Once it is finished, you're done!

Comment: I ended up just erasing the drive because Parted would not let me change the partitions.

Comment: @user549775 did you follow my directions exactly?